# Как отправить calllback автоматически в aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

у меня есть функция:

```
async def generate_fairytale_pdf(id, self_image=None):
    ...
    with open(f"{pages[0]}", "rb") as image:
        await bot.send_photo(id, image)
```

Могу ли я как то, без участия пользователя, сразу после отправки фото, перейти в другой блок кода, с обработчиком:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: True)
async def process_callback_language(call, state: FSMContext):
    ...
    # Главное меню fairytale
    if call.data == 'fairytale_menu':
        text = f"Настрой свою профессиональную новеллу! ⚙️"
        for button in K.fairytale_menu:
            keyboard.add(button)
        await call.message.edit_text(text=text, reply_markup=keyboard)
```

мне нужно после отправки фото, перейти в главное меню fairytale

Answer (score 0):

вы можете сразу после отправки сообщения с фото прикрепить клавиатуру в async def generate_fairytale_pdf

```
async def generate_fairytale_pdf(id, self_image=None):
    ...
    with open(f"{pages[0]}", "rb") as image:
        await bot.send_photo(id, image)
    text = f"Настрой свою профессиональную новеллу! ⚙️"
    for button in K.fairytale_menu:
        keyboard.add(button)
    await call.message.send_message(text=text, reply_markup=keyboard)
```